# How to access server.js file url in react app.js file using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Please tell me how should I do
server.js

```
app.get('/playlist', (req, res) => {
    fetch("http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/playlist.json")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end("Failed to load data: " + err);
        });
})
```

React app.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/playlist').then(function(response){
     alert(response)
   }).catch(function(error){
     alert(error)
   });
}
```

Comment: Are your server and client apart of the same project? Try putting the full url in axios.get: axios.get('http:// localhost/playlist')

Comment: Yes in a same project. but client runs on http://localhost:8080/ and server runs on http://localhost:8181/  so how to give the URL please tell me.

Comment: What happens when you put localhost:8181/playlist? Same error?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8181/playlist net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  . It is giving Like that error . please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but it looks like you don't have a semicolon at the end of your app.get block. If you're using ES6 syntax that shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: now that problem is resolve but it is not fetching actual output from nodejs. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App</title>
  <link href="/8e69941b2fcf3e9b2cae.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="react"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/8e69941b2fcf3e9b2cae.js"></script></body>
</html>   ..... Now it is giving like that response. But I dont want this

Comment: Put console.log statements in your nodejs to see what's being executed. If your catch block is being executed then you can console.log(err) to see what it is.

Comment: Seems like a cross origin error. The Ajax requests to localhost:8181 but the origin is localhost:8080, not the same origin.

Comment: Try these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors